# -Python- Principiante- Bucle / For . Donde esta mal?

Tags: python

Hace pocos días estoy aprendiendo de cero a programar. Y quise crear un programa que realice lo siguiente:

**1)** Que me muestre un mensaje de bienvenida y me consulte por el nombre. (hasta ahí bien)

**2)** Dentro de ese "nombre" que verifique que sean solo letras y no números.

**3)** Que el bucle se repita si sigo poniendo números.

Con lo que aprendí hasta el momento hice lo siguiente, pero pase lo que pase me lleva a la linea `print("Se ingreso un digito, solo se aceptan letras")` Que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

```
print( "Bienvenido a XXXXXXXX. Por favor complete su Legajo de ingreso" )

validonombre = False
nombre=input( "Ingrese por favor su nombre: " )

for i in nombre:
    if( i == 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ):     
    validonombre=True

if validonombre == True:
    print( "Se ingreso un digito, solo se aceptan letras" )
    nombre = input( "Ingrese por favor su nombre: " )
else: 
    print( "Nombre ingresado correctamente" )
```

Comment: la funcion `input()` siempre te devuelve un string ya la recorrer cada letra estas comparando `"1" == 1` lo cual nunca se cumplirá, adema la forma de comparar tambien esta mal

Comment: que quisiste hacer aca? if(i==1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Corrigiendo la condición

Vamos a corregir tu condición `if(i==1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`. Para corregirla, vamos a tener en cuenta estos puntos:

- Para saber si algo se encuentra dentro de una tupla, se usa el operador [in](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/in-and-not-in-operators-in-python).
- Las tuplas deben estar encerradas entre paréntesis.
- Tu comparación no tiene en cuenta el caso de que el usuario ingrese el numero 0 en su nombre.
- "i" es el resultado de obtener un carácter de una cadena, por lo que "i" también es una cadena, no un número. Por ejemplo (programáticamente hablando) el numero 0 NO ES IGUAL a la cadena "0". Por lo que incluso si tomamos en cuenta los puntos anteriores. Si el usuario ingresa un 1 en su nombre, ese "1" nunca estará en la tupla (1,2,3,4,...). Para que un numero sea considerado una cadena, debe de estar entre comillas.

Teniendo en cuenta todos estos puntos, tu condición quedaría así:

```
if(i in ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")):
```

#### Unos métodos de cadena que considero que pueden ser utiles.

**[str.isdecimal](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isdecimal)**

Esta función se encarga de saber si todos los caracteres en una cadena son números. Eso incluye a cadenas de un solo carácter.
Eso significa que un equivalente de esta condición `if(i in ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")):` sería `if(i.isdecimal())`.

**[str.isalpha](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isalpha)**

Esta función es bastante útil. Revisa que todos los caracteres de la cadena sean puramente letras del alfabeto. Probé y también considera a la ñ y las vocales acentuadas letras!!!
Eso significa que este código:

```
print("Bienvenido a XXXXXXXX. Por favor complete su Legajo de ingreso")

validonombre=False
nombre=input("Ingrese por favor su nombre: ")

if(not nombre.isalpha()):
    print("nombre incorrecto")
```

Considera como nombre incorrecto el nombre si contiene las siguientes cosas:

- Espacios.
- Numeros.
- Simbolos (!, ", ., :, etc)

str.alpha funciona muy similar a isdecimal, y también puedes verificar si cadenas de un solo caracter son letras. Por ejemplo "1".alpha() va a dar falso, mientras que "a".alpha() va a dar verdadero.

Comment: nuevamente me estaba complicando la vida :/

Comment: Muchas gracias! Voy a tener en cuenta lo mencionado. Paso a paso.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de que sea un proyecto destinado a funcionar, más allá de la práctica de habilidades, recomendaría rediseñar la lógica para garantizar la reusabilidad del código, así como orientarlo a objetos por si luego debe ser parte de algo más grande, pero tomémoslo tal cual:

```
print( "Bienvenido a XXXXXXXX. Por favor complete su Legajo de ingreso" )

# esta variable es prescindible, solo con fines didácticos
# para hacer más claro el código
msj = "por favor ingrese su nombre.\n Asegúrese de usar solamente caracteres alfabéticos A-Z a-z"

nombre="creamos la variable en el ámbito del programa"
while True
    nombre =input(msj)
    if nombre.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print (" usar solamente caracteres alfabéticos en el nombre\n\n")
```